# How to clear a SQL Table when Database has a point in its name (bash script)?

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, sql-delete

*The script is in `/etc/cron.daily`.*

---

When I had `database name = baseName` and the `table = tableName`, the below script to empty the table worked well :

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -u root --password=PASSWD -e "DELETE FROM baseName.tableName"
```

---

But I needed to rename the database in `baseName.fr.value` so I basically modified my script to

```
#!/bin/bash

mysql -u root --password=PASSWD -e "DELETE FROM baseName.fr.value.tableName"
```

But I got an `You have an error in your SQL syntax, check the manual...`

---

So what's the correct syntax when there's a `.` in the database name ?

Comment: Try putting square brackets around the full name

Comment: @user1178830 neither `[baseName.fr.value.tableName]` nor `[baseName.fr.value].tableName` work :/

Comment: @user1178830 That's SQL-Server syntax. MySQL uses backticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you put backticks around database, table, or column names that contain special characters.

```
mysql -u root --password=PASSWD -e 'DELETE FROM `baseName.fr.value`.tableName'
```

Note that I changed from double quotes to single quotes, because backticks have special meaning to the shell when used inside double quotes.

See [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and back ticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql) and [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).